# Using constants in object declaration?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to create a function pointer object:

```
private var func:Object = { Class.Constant: function };
```

What is the clean way of doing this?  I did the above and got

```
Error: Syntax error: expecting colon before dot.
```

And I'm not even sure that's right.  The goal is that I can just do

```
func[ Constants ]();
```

somewhere later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private var func:Object = { };
func[ Class.CONSTANT ] = function() { };
```

Comment: So there's no doing it in one go?

Comment: I just added a definition example.

Comment: The example of doing it during definition is deceiving, and not a solution.  That will use 'KEY' as the key of the func object instead of the value of Class.CONSTANT.   

For example   
var FOO:String = "foo"; 
var obj:Object = {FOO: "bar"};   
trace(obj.FOO); // "bar"   
trace(obj[FOO]); // undefined.
trace(obj["foo"]); // undefined.

Basically there's no way to use variables or constants when defining an object.